# Splitting the values column using split function in R

Tags: r, split

I have tab delimited text where Column 1 shows the cars and the Column 2 has its corresponding hits. In the below examples Car_1 has only hits while Car_3 and Car_4 has 2 and 3 hits respectively. They are given as as follows:

```
>df
     Car    Hits
    Car_1 omini|red|90%
    Car_2
    Car_3 Skoda|blue|97%
          Audi|orange|96%
          Ibiza|white|96%
    Car_6 Honda|black|93%
          BMW|blue|100%
```

I would like split the second column so that multiple hits for Car_3 and Car_6 are arranged in single tab separated rows like follows

```
>df
     Car     Hits
    Car_1 omini|red|90%
    Car_2
    Car_3 Skoda|blue|97% Audi|orange|96% Ibiza|white|96%   
    Car_6 honda|black|93% BMW|blue|100%
```

I tried the following code in R but it didn’t work

```
>split(df,df$Hits)
```

Can anyone help me in getting desired output.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample data:**

```
df = data.frame(Cars = c("Car_1", "Car_2", "Car_3", "", "", "Car_6", ""), Hits = c("omini|red|90%", "", "Skoda|blue|97%", "Audi|orange|96%", "Ibiza|white|96%", "Honda|black|93%", "BMW|blue|100%"))
```

p)

**Edited 
solution**:

---

```
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]){ if(df$Hits[i] != "" && df$Cars[i] == ""){ df$Cars[i] = df$Cars[i-1]}}

required = aggregate(Hits ~ Cars, data = df, paste, collapse = " ")
```

Comment: By using the above command, it splitts the "|" into a separate column but I want to group the multiple hits for particular car in a single row.

Comment: Nope, all I got was column2 is splited into 3 more columns one for car name,another for colour and another for percentage. What I want is to appned each of multiple hits for car_3 and car_6 in a single row.

Comment: provide a reproducible example to avoid confusions

Comment: @Dinesh is that what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(car=c("Car_1", "Car_2","Car_3","Car_3","Car_3","Car_6","Car_6"), 
                 Hits=c("omini|red|90%", "", "Skoda|blue|97%", "Audi|orange|96%", "Ibiza|white|96%", "Honda|black|93%","BMW|blue|100% ")) 

   > df
        car            Hits
    1 Car_1   omini|red|90%
    2 Car_2                
    3 Car_3  Skoda|blue|97%
    4 Car_3 Audi|orange|96%
    5 Car_3 Ibiza|white|96%
    6 Car_6 Honda|black|93%
    7 Car_6  BMW|blue|100% 
    > ddply(data.frame(df), .(car), summarise,Names=paste(Hits, collapse=" "))
        car                                      Names
    1 Car_1                                  omini|red|90%
    2 Car_2                                               
    3 Car_3 Skoda|blue|97% Audi|orange|96% Ibiza|white|96%
    4 Car_6                 Honda|black|93% BMW|blue|100%
```

Comment: hi Prasana,your code it get the output in desired format rather it prints it all hits of second column in a single row

Comment: @Dinesh , the desired format - you have asked in the question is achieved. Not sure what you exactly wanted

Comment: I got your point. How did you Car_3 two times to to right of "Audi|orange|96%" and "Ibiza|white|96%" also one time to right of "BMW|blue|100%". If I get that then it will be easy

Comment: @Dinesh i crated a reproducible example ,to showcase the solution

Comment: @ Prasanna your answer is absolutely correct but if you look at the data shown by dinesh there are empty strings and thats why its not working for dinesh. I have made a sample data in my answer exactly like he has shown

Comment: @Dinesh please try the solution in my answer, it should work for you I hope. After running "for loop" step you can also use Prasanna's solution which includes ddply, it will work fine.